# find -exec doesn't run the exec part

Tags: linux, shell, find, exec, ucd

I am executing the following commands in a UrbanCode Deploy Shell step. What I want is run the Util.sh against all files being found.

```
find . -type f -exec ls -al {} \;
find . -type f -exec Util.sh -import source= {} overwrite=true \;
Util.sh
```

The output is as follows, and **the 2nd command didn't run at all.**

```
delimiter specified is ,
executing script for all values in /app/bip/XMLP/Reports

-------------------------------
executing script for values: /app/bip/XMLP/Reports
/bin/sh /var/tmp/shell_command_5832071109593396198.tmp /app/bip/XMLP/Reports 
-------------------------------
command output: 
./BIP_Rollfoward/tmp/FlexPak/Asset_Allocation/Asset_Allocation.xdmz
./BIP_Rollfoward/tmp/FlexPak/Asset_Allocation/Asset_Allocation.xdoz
/var/tmp/shell_command_5832071109593396198.tmp: Util.sh: not found
===============================
command exit code: 1
```

Comment: `/var/tmp/shell_command_5832071109593396198.tmp: Util.sh: not found`

Answer (score 0):

I had to change ownership of a directory with a too long list of files so I used the following find command. I would have used "\;" to close the exec but it didn't work.

```
find /path/to/dir -name \* -exec chown user:group {} +
```

This code worked on version 6.1.3

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the space between '=' and '{' in source= {}

Should be:

```
source={}
```